# How can I verify if one string variable is equal to a specific string that is not a variable in a do while in C language?? (not compare two strings)

Tags: c, string, verification

I have already read the C string function man pages. The best thing I found was "strcmp" and "strncmp". But that's not what I want because it compares two strings. I just want to compare one like this...

```
char input[3];
    do {
        //important code
        printf ("You want to continue??);
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(input);
       } while (input == "yes" || "Yes);
```

It doesn't work. I would need to not use string and just a char like: "y" for yes. Is there a way I can do what I want? How can I compare just this one string with these values?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: You want to compare two strings. It doesn't matter that one of them is const. == would only compare their addresses, so always evaluates false for different objects.

Comment: No errors, but the program simply don't do what is expected, it keeps on the do while and don't go further on the code. So the program gets stuck there you see...

Comment: Don't [`fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7898516/694733).

Comment: If you want to compare a one-character response, you could do something like `while (input[0] == 'y' || input[0] == 'Y';`.

Comment: Don't declare a tiny array like `char input[3];` to hold a line the user's going to type — the user might type more than you expect.  And never use the `gets` function to read such lines, because you can't tell it how big your array is, so it can't be careful not to overflow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make string comparison, use `strcmp`. You will compare just one variable, as you want it, but with two different values. Change line :

```
while (input == "yes" || "Yes");
```

to :

```
while ( strcmp(input,"yes") == 0 || strcmp(input, "Yes") == 0);
```

Also, change :

```
char input[3];
```

to :

```
char input[4];
```

as you need to take into account the terminating `\0` character.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You sure the extra char is needed cuz of the null "\0" stuff about arrays? How I give you reputation?? I cant vote yet, sorry!

Comment: @Speyke every string ends with the terminating character `\0`, yes :) Glad I helped! You gave me reputation by accepting my answer, if you want to upvote, you can press the upper triangle at the left of the answer :)

Comment: You should not change `input[3]` to `input[4]`.  You should change it to `input[100];`.  Memory is cheap, and users sometimes type more than you expect.

Comment: Also you should *never* use a function that, like `gets`, reads arbitrary-length input into an array which you're not able to tell it the size of.  In such a case, there's no way to prevent buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here I wrote a simple solution for what you're trying to achieve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char input[4];

    do {
        printf ("You want to continue??");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(input);
    } while (strcmp(input, "yes") == 0 || strcmp(input, "Yes") == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanksssss! How I give you reputation?? I cant vote yet, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are going run into newline character that gets carried over
to next input.  Here is a solution for that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
   char input[4], garbage[50];
   do 
   {
      //important code
      printf ("You want to continue??");
      scanf("%s", input);
      fgets(garbage, sizeof(garbage), stdin); //Newline char is now stored into garbage.
    } while (strcmp(input,"yes") == 0 || strcmp(input,"Yes") == 0 );

   return 0;
}
```